# HTML5, background video not running when I add content over it

Tags: css, html, video

I am creating a simple portfolio page on github and am using HTML, CSS, and JS.
I have 4 different sections on my page, that I created a scroll functionality to nav through the portfolio. 
I have added a background video to the first(home) section of the page. When i added it directly into the body tag it worked and played fine. But I needed it to be the background of my "home section"..so when I finally aligned it correctly to fit the home-page, it didn't play.
the background is of a video-still, not the poster="./videos/Lonely-Blue.jpg" that I plugged in as an alt image..which means it just wont start playing. I haven't been able to find a solution that has worked yet, but I've mainly been testing with the placement of the video in HTML and with CSS.

here is the HTML snippet:

```
<ul id="myMenu">
  <li data-menuanchor="welcome" class="active"><a href="#welcome">Home</a>   </li>
  <li data-menuanchor="about"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li data-menuanchor="projects"><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
  <li data-menuanchor="contact"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="fullpage">

  <div class="section" data-menuanchor="welcome" id="homeSection">
    <div id = "bg-vid">
    <video preload playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="./videos/Lonely-Blue.jpg" id="bgvid">
        <source src="./videos/Lonely-Blue.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="./videos/Lonely-Blue.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
    <div id="wrapper" class="home">
      <h1 id ="dbg">Diana B. Gobar</h1>
      <h5>Full Stack Web Developer. Artist. Curious human.<br><span id="highlight">Get to know me: </span><span id="altFaves"> ...</span></h5>
    </div>
```

the **CSS** for the video and home section:

```
#bg-vid {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

#homeSection {
  z-index: -2;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 60px;
}

.home{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;*/
  /*background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);*/
}
```

The navigation bar on top of the video worked fine while it played, but when I aligned the size of the video with the home section and added the "wrapper" content over it, it wont start.

Answer (score 0):

Try to mannualy start the video,
insert after the snippet

```
<script>
    // assuming you're using jQuery
    $('#bg-vid video')[0].play()
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but that wasn't working for some reason either.

Comment: I'm using jQuery, and tried adding that again. Also, I'm working on an up-to-date browser...i believe it has to do with the placement of the video but I definitely need that content on the video